# ggplot for multiple curves and data types

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to make a plot with ggplot that shows multiple curves of fundamental frequency over time. I am looking at different kinds of words, with data from multiple tokens for each type (for simplicity I called these types 1, 2, and 3, and labelled the tokens from 1 to 20). For the simple data set I have just ten time points (labelled 1-10) and the F0 values associated with them. I want a graph that has the different types of words in different colored graphs, but with the different tokens within those types all being within the same color. I would imagine that using aes(), the 'colour' would be defined by word, and the x would be time and y would be f0 values. Whenever I try to code my data into R it tells me I am getting undefined columns. The code I am using looks like this:

```
theme_set(theme_bw())
myf0 <- ggplot(ent, aes(x = Time, groups = token, colour = word))
myf0 <- myf0 + geom_line(aes(y = F0), alpha = 0.8)
myf0 <- myf0 + ylab("Hz")
```

However, when I go to plot myf0 it tells me this:

```
Error in `[.data.frame`(data, "group") : undefined columns selected
```

What am I doing wrong? Thank you!

Point of clarification:
Sorry I forgot to add a snippet of data! Here is what it looks like:

```
  word token Time        F0
1    1     1    1  107.8968
2    1     1    2  113.1362
3    1     1    3  117.2904
4    1     1    4  127.3287
5    1     1    5  132.7554
6    1     1    6  126.4456
7    1     1    7 111.19686
8    1     1    8  93.87390
9    1     1    9  87.12876
10   1     1   10  86.40445
```

Where word goes from 1 to 3, token from 1 to 20 (there are 20 tokens in each of the word classes, so 60 tokens total), time goes from 1 to 10 for each token, and there is an F0 value for each point.

So a short snippet of my data for the simple example, where I get the error by trying to make the ggplot work would look like:

```
   word token Time        F0
1     1     1    1 107.89677
2     1     1    2 113.13620
3     1     1    3 117.29039
11    1     2    1 117.0063
12    1     2    2 119.6887
13    1     2    3 116.1143
201   2     1    1 125.25897
202   2     1    2 119.52722
203   2     1    3 115.67006
211   2     2    1 101.54531
212   2     2    2 102.27651
213   2     2    3 100.96099
401   3     1    1  98.82212
402   3     1    2  98.82212
403   3     1    3  97.78813
411   3     2    1  95.15890
412   3     2    2  97.76110
413   3     2    3 100.42595
```

Hope this helps! Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please add a [minimal, reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610). Cheers.

Comment: Yes, maybe `head(ent)`?

Comment: Done! Along with a tiny version of the data set I was using.

Comment: I believe you just need to change the word `groups` to the argument name `group`.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want? One line per token within word, with lines coloured by word.

```
ent$word <- as.factor(ent$word)
ent$token <- as.factor(ent$token)

ggplot(ent, aes(x = Time, y = F0, group = interaction(word, token), colour = word)) +
  geom_line() + 
  ylab("Hz") +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]